# Burninate or clean up the tags [freeware] and [shareware]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Could we burninate or clean up the tags [freeware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freeware) (76 questions) and [shareware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shareware) (34 questions)?
They are meta tags without explanation about the topic, usually used for off topic searches for software or licence issues.

Comment: But if they're burninated, we can't search by them to delete bad questions.

Comment: For a glimpse, I saw some of those questions were upvoted, so I assume the questions themselves are not the problem, only the tag.

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't think being upvoted could justify an Off Topic question. There are some among them which are not searching for external resources, so if there is no other (OT) reason these should not be closed.

Comment: I agree with that, though I *admit* I only saw it for a glimpse from the question list without considering the content. I support the clean-up first.

Comment: I've flagged and left downvotes on freeware. I saw a mod helped out as well.

Comment: @rene thanks, and special thanks to  Bill the Lizard.

Comment: Shouldn't most of these be in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @bummi we did what we could: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20708344#20708344

Comment: @pnuts I think I did what can be done, voted edited where I was was the opinion of it might be useful, always grateful to learn something new so if you would have suggestions what I should have done better please tell me. IMHO, fact is close votes for older questions tend to age out before being handled, so a cooperative handling these should be more effective.

Comment: @pnuts my prior intention is to to get rid of some OT questions which are cumulated on these tags, since they are attracting spam and VLQ answers and so would fill the VLQ queue, I did some edits, but  I'm not always familiar  enough with the topic to decide how to judge on a specific questions, this is the point I'd like to get some help from the community.Still I won't see a need for the shareware tag at least.

Comment: [tag:freeware] is empty [tag.shareware] still carries 16 questions

Answer (score -2):

I think we should Burninate the tags as I personally feel that is off topic for Stack Overflow. The point of stack overflow is to find help with your code. Not find programs